# How to get document from Kivik by field other than ID

Tags: go, couchdb, kivik

I need to fetch a document from DB using kivik in Go but the inbuild get function in Kivik allows you to get value only by using the ID of the document. Is there a way to get document by using field other than the document ID.

Here is the link that I am referring - https://github.com/go-kivik/kivik/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Find](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-kivik/kivik/v3?tab=doc#DB.Find). See [CouchDB docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-find) for query semantics.